# Keep cache between recompiles in Play Framework 2.2 / Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

Is it possible to keep the cache 'loaded' between recompiles?

Using auto-compile mode (play ~run) it calls out to several external APIs to build the response. If I am just tweaking code it is a pain to have to wait to rebuild the whole page every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the nature of development mode. The server is restarted for every recompile, and the `EhCachePlugin` is reinitialized. In production however, you shouldn't be using the `EhCachePlugin` anyway, as it not designed for a distributed environment (since each instance has it's own local cache).

I use the [Play2-Memcached](https://github.com/mumoshu/play2-memcached) plugin for my production servers, and after a lot of similar frustration, I just decided to install memcached on my local machine and use that in development mode as well. I'm only kicking myself for not doing it sooner. It also comes with the added bonus of being able to `flushall` from the command line.